# Conversion technique/tool from temporal logic CTL,CTL* or LTL to μ-calculus

Tags: lo.logic, program-verification, temporal-logic

Suppose one wants to use a μ-calculus model checker, but specify things in temporal logics, which is easier (more intuitive). Is there a technique (even better, a tool) that automatically translates formulae in any of these logics (CTL,CTL* or LTL) to the μ-calculus?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: http://www.win.tue.nl/~jfg/articles/CSR-10-09.pdf It's doable.

Comment: I am confused as to why you are asking this question, given that I answered your cs.stackexchange question with references. http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16610/163

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I just thought that the question is hidden in the discussion and hoped that more people will see it as a stand alone question. Cheers

Comment: In addition to Vijay D's comment, you also asked the exact same question [Techniques (tools) to convert temporal logic (CTL,CTL* or LTL) to μ-calculus formulae](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18196/techniques-tools-to-convert-temporal-logic-ctl-ctl-or-ltl-to-calculus-for/18200#18200) 2 days ago and I also suggested an answer.